# A question on stochastic integral

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a question in some middle steps of a proof of some theorem.
Here is the condition we need:
Let $B(t)$ be an $\mathbb{R}^m$-valued Brownian motion. Consider the $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued SIE,
$$X_t=x+\int_a^t f(s,X_s)ds+\int_a^t \sigma(s,X_s)dB(s),\quad a\leq t\leq b$$
where the matrix valued $\sigma(t,x)$ and vector valued $f(t,x)$ are measurable and satisfy linear growth and Lipschitz condition. Assume that $\sigma(t,x)$ and $f(t,x)$ are continuous on $[a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am trying to show that
$$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right)=O(\epsilon^2)$$

My attempt:

\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right) \\
& =\mathbb{E}\left( \sqrt{\left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_i(s,X_s)ds\right]^2} \sqrt{\left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_j(s,X_s)ds\right]^2} \right) \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}\left( \left[\epsilon\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_i^2(s,X_s)ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\epsilon\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_j^2(s,X_s)ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \quad \text{Cauchy-Schwartz} \\
& =\mathbb{E}\left( \epsilon\left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_i^2(s,X_s)ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_j^2(s,X_s)ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \\
& =\epsilon\mathbb{E}\left( \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_i^2(s,X_s)ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} f_j^2(s,X_s)ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \\
& =\epsilon \left( \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} \mathbb{E}\left(f_i^2(s,X_s)\right)ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} \mathbb{E}\left(f_j^2(s,X_s)\right)ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \\
\end{align}

First question: I am unsure about the validity of the last equality. Why $f_i$ and $f_j$ are independent to each other? Is it because $f$ and $\sigma$ are deterministic functions?

If it's correct, then I may continue as follows:

\begin{align}
& =\epsilon \left( \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} \mathbb{E}\left(f_i^2(s,X_s)\right)ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} \mathbb{E}\left(f_j^2(s,X_s)\right)ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \\
& \leq \epsilon \left( \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} C_1(1+\mathbb{E}(|X_s|^2)) ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} C_2(1+\mathbb{E}(|X_s|^2)) ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \\
& \leq \epsilon \left( \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} C_1' ds\right]^{1/2} \left[\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon} C_2' ds\right]^{1/2} \right) \\
& =O(\epsilon^2)
\end{align}

Second question: For the first inequality above, I used the condition that the $f$ satisfies linear growth condition: $|f(t,x)|^2\leq C(1+|x|^2)$. But then how do I show $\mathbb{E}(|X_s|^2)$ is finite? I know it may be related to quadratic variation property of Brownian motion, but how do I write out the proof rigorously?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to pull the expectation into the integrals? Then you would just have to show that $e(u,s) = \mathbb{E}[f_i(X_u,u)f_j(X_s,s)]$ fulfills some necessary condition for the integrals to be $O(\epsilon^2)$ (boundedness I suppose?)

Comment: Then how do you isolate the two integral? i.e., E[AB]=E[A]E[B]?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds \right) \mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right)$ because $f_i$ and $f_j$ are independent.

Comment: @TalkingPuppet I think  a_student means something like $\mathbb E\left[\int \int f(s,X_s)f(u,X_u)dsdu\right]=\int \int\mathbb E\left[ f(s,X_s)f(u,X_u)\right]dsdu$

Comment: @Chaos Then how do you show $\mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right) = \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left(f_i(s,X_s) f_j(u,X_u)\right)dsdu   $

Comment: You should use the Fubini-Tonelli lemma (for instance if you assume the boundedness of $f$)

Comment: @Chaos There is no such assumption of boundness of $f$ here.

Comment: I think the linear growth condition is enough in this case.

Comment: $Chaos I edited my answer just now. Do you mind checking it again or give a full explain of your method? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chaos I think I got the idea why you mentioned linear growth condition. Since $|f(s,X_s)|^2\leq C(1+|X_s|^2)$ by linear growth condition then $\mathbb{E}[|f(s,X_s)|^2]\leq C(1+\mathbb{E}[|X_s|^2])<\infty$. I am only unsure about the last inequality. I think it is because of the finite quadratic variation property of Brownian motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E}\left( \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds \int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right) \\
\leq & \sqrt{ \mathbb{E}\left(\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i(s,X_s)ds\right)^2 \mathbb{E}\left(\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j(s,X_s)ds \right)^2 } \\
\leq & \sqrt{ \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_i^2(s,X_s)ds\right) \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}f_j^2(s,X_s)ds \right)} \\
\leq & \epsilon\int_{t}^{t+\epsilon}\mathbb{E}\left(1+|X_s|^2\right)ds \\
= & O(\epsilon^2)
\end{align}